# In expressjs using mongoose how i print data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new in mongoose.I am trying to print data form my mongodb using mongoose .
My code -

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dbname');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var dbSchema = new Schema({
   name:  String,
   url: String,
   category:   { name: String, path: String },  
});
var db = mongoose.model('db',dbSchema, 'colection_name');
console.log(db.url);
```

My mongodb -

```
 {
     "name": "xxxx",
     "url": "http://localhost/kayiIU9g3443",
     "category" : {
          "name": "yyyy",
          "path": "ggggg"
      },
  }
```

Comment: You've just created a model, if you want actual data from the DB you have to insert some data, then do a query as well to get it back ?

Comment: in my db already have data .Is it require to insert ?

Comment: You don't have to insert anything if the data you want is already there, but you to get it with a query

Comment: i try to see the data using console  console.log(db.url); .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     db.find(function (err, db) {
          if (err) return console.error(err);
           console.dir(db);
     });
```